# How to improve answers which only cover part of a topic

Tags: discussion, answers

I want to get involved more in closing the unanswered questions. Since I do not have many permissions as a newcomer, I encounter some trouble.

If there is an answer which covers **only a part** of the topic, what should I do to improve it?

- Edit the answer to add information?
- Create new answer?
- Just add a comment, hoping that somebody will merge the information to the actual answer?
- Although "do nothing" is also a valid alternative.

Of course, I will not mind raising my reputation in the process ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to get involved more in closing the unanswered questions.

I think you mean you want to get more involved in ***answering*** unanswered questions. (On the Stack Exchange, questions are **closed** when they are found to be off-topic for some reason.)

> Since I do not have many permissions as a newcomer...

The best thing to do about this is to write high-quality questions and answers that will help you gain reputation (and [privileges](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)). It only takes 125 points to earn the twelve most fundamental privileges, which would be enough that you wouldn't really be restricted in the situation you describe.

---

> If there is an answer which covers **only a part** of the topic, what should I do to improve it?
>      • Edit the answer to add information?
>      • Create new answer?
>      • Just add a comment, hoping that somebody will merge the information to the actual answer?

I think two of those are valid responses, and one should generally be avoided.

**When should you add a comment?** If the point you are making is a minor clarification, or a rare exception, a comment can be a nice way to augment a solid answer.

**When should you leave another answer?** There is nothing wrong with starting an answer with something like:

> The answer written by `<username>` is a good one, and I agree with it. But there is one other situation that is worth mentioning.

If there are multiple answers already, but you want to reference one in particular, you can add a link to the answer you are referring to. However, avoid phrases such as:

> The answer above this one is good.

because you don't know where your answer will appear in relation the one you are referencing. (Answers can be displayed in an order dictated by the time they were posted or by the number of upvotes they have received, so an answer that appears **below** another answer today may appear **above** that answer next week. Moreover, accepted answers usually appear at the top regardless of time posted or number of upvotes.)

**What about editing the answer?** For the most part, I would recommend shying away from this option: *Edit the answer to add information*. If there is really some significant factoid that ought to be included, I think it's best to say so in a comment or your own answer.

The [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) says this about editing:

> Editing is encouraged! Some common reasons to edit are:
>      • to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
>      • to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
>      • to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
>      • to add related resources or hyperlinks

That said, if you feel like an answer is "only covering part of a topic," that goes a little bit beyond "clarifying the meaning of a post **without changing it**". In short, if you want to **expand** an answer, I think that it would usually be best to do so via comments and/or additional answers.

Answer (score 1):

I often just add another answer that starts with:

> To add on to so-and-so's (excellent) answer: ...

followed by whatever is so important that it couldn't be neglected.

Comment: On one hand this is fine if you don't want to go over the same ground or you're limited in time, but you should keep in mind that people can remove or change their answers, and you might never know that your answer has been turned into a half answer. It doesn't hurt to restate what someone else has said if you want to expand on it, e.g. As @Andrew has already explained, the discombobulator is twinged by the recompensator. It's also worthwhile to know that  recompensators often occur in pairs.

Comment: @ColleenV  Yes, that's an unfortunate consequence of the site design.  I usually do this for accepted answers, but even though I hate to repeat what someone else has already said, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I understand not liking to repeat things, but also consider that sometimes stating an idea from a different perspective can help people understand it more easily. I don't mean to push you to repeat points in other answers, just offering a couple of things to think about.

Comment: @ColleenV: +1 for the "discombobulator " :)) Which seems to be the action of "discombobulate", which was originally "discombobricate"